# HTML and css position of text can't be changed

Tags: html, css, text

I'm a student from Belgium. I'm creating my portfolio website and I came across an error
that I cannot fix. My teacher advised me to post a question here for help.

As you can see in the screenshot the bold text is acting weird. It should act like the lower text part.
Is there any way to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/moxiF.jpg

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<div class = "intro" id="introtext">
<h2 id="h2intro">My name is not Joren and I am a <span class="cyan">designer</span>      from Belgium. </h2>
<h3 class="h3intro">I am passionate about making very <span class="cyan">simple and clean</span> designs that are easy on the eye and very simple to use.</h3>
</div><!--end intro-->
```

**CSS**

```
.cyan
{
    color:#00d1e0;
}

#h2intro
{
    font-weight: bold;

}

.h3intro
{
    color: #463E3F;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Joren

Comment: first, why are you using an ID (#h2intro) for one header and a class for another (.h3intro)?

Comment: Your teacher is very wise to send you here, might I add

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RJxBy/

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that. I changed the ID to a class.

Comment: http://cyberiadesign.be/Test/      It works for everything except the mobile one.

Comment: Do you have any other css on your page. It is probably something else that is causing the problem.

Comment: We can not find solution, coz here everything is alright http://jsfiddle.net/P6f4Z/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to change the default font-size for both h2 and h3 to the same size. Try

```
 h2, h3 {
      font-size:14px; 
}

 #h2intro {
     font-weight: bold;

 }

 .h3intro {
     color: #463E3F; }
```

i believe you have set default styles to H2 and H3. This is why you are seeing padding and size differences. you can additionally set the size in #h2intro and .h3intro if you don't want to affect the other h2 and h3 tags.

**In response to a comment, please use the following styles at the bottom of the stylesheet.**

```
#introtext h2.h2intro  
{ 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
 } 

#introtext h3.h3intro 
{  
   font-size: 14px; 
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   color: #463E3F; 
}
```

Comment: do you have styles defined for h2 and h3 below .h3intro? if so, those styles would overwrite the h2 and h3 style i provided.

Comment: #introtext
{
 background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#introtext h2
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

#introtext h3
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

Comment: there you go. You are overwriting the style. I will edit my post with a more clearly defined CSS selector. Please put them both at the bottom of your stylesheet.

Comment: Still the same issue.  
cyberiadesign.be/Test     You can see the css and the HTL completely there :)

Comment: please see my edits. If I were you I would take some time to better understrand CSS, and define your styles very carefully.

Comment: whats the desired outcome? the text all the same size, but one part just bold? why not use the same type of header?

Comment: I just don't want to padding it has on the right. The top part needs to be bold text.

Comment: I've just found the issue :D there were two elements on visibility hidden instead of display none :)

Comment: ahh, im glad you found you issue. next time you have an issue it would be good to post your entire HTML and CSS using js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/.